# TYPO3 - cache tagging and flushing - more than one tag per request

Tags: typo3

I have following case:

1. Records are displayed both in single (showAction) and list view with pagination (listAction) and in some other actions also.
2. I would like to flush caches from within Scheduler for given single record - both on single view and on list view - only appropriate pages.

So in showAction there is:

```
   public function showAction(...) {
   ...
        $this->addCacheTags('RecordName_' . $item->getUid());
   ...
```

Then in Scheduler I can use something like that to remove caches:

```
$this->cacheManager = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance('TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Cache\\CacheManager');
$this->cacheManager->getCache('cache_pages')->flushByTag('RecordName_' . $item->getUid());
$this->cacheManager->getCache('cache_pagesection')->flushByTag('RecordName_' . $item->getUid());
```

This will work fine for singleView but not for actions where there is more than one record to be tagged, since following in listAction will not work as desired in my case (only one tag per request can be addedd):

```
   foreach($products as $product){
            $this->addCacheTags('RecordName_' . $product->getUid());
        }
```

Anyone has solution how to achieve that with use of TYPO3 core cache functionality?

Answer (score 5):

If you really want to tag a list view with so many tags (which i do not suggest, see below), you can add multiple tags per request in TYPO3:

```
$GLOBALS['TSFE']->addCacheTags(['RecordName_1', 'RecordName_2', 'RecordName_3']);
```

The drawback of tagging a list view with record uid's is, that you'd still need another cache tag to properly cache-clear the list view for new records (as the tag for the new uid has not yet been added to the cache tags).
Therefore it's better to add tags that describe the current search query (which'd also fit your "only one tag per request" requirement):

```
// list view for records stored in pid 10
$GLOBALS['TSFE']->addCacheTags(['RecordName_pid_10']);

// list view by category with uid 30
$GLOBALS['TSFE']->addCacheTags(['RecordName_category_30']);

// single view for uid 1
$GLOBALS['TSFE']->addCacheTags(['RecordName_1']);
```

Now in your scheduler command you need to clear some more cache tags. You may use `flushCachesInGroupByTag` to not call `flushByTags` for `cache_pages` and `cache_pagesection` implicitly AND to support extensions that add custom page caches like EXT:nc_staticfilecache or EXT:nginx_cache.

```
$this->cacheManager = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance('TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Cache\\CacheManager');
$this->cacheManager->flushCachesInGroupByTag('pages', 'RecordName_' . $item->getUid());
$this->cacheManager->flushCachesInGroupByTag('pages', 'RecordName_pid_' . $item->getPid());
```

Note: If you're already on TYPO3 8.5 you may use `flushByTags(array)`/`flushCachesInGroupByTag(array)` to flush multiple tags per cache at once. [1]

```
$this->cacheManager = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance('TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Cache\\CacheManager');
$this->cacheManager->flushCachesInGroupByTags('pages', ['RecordName_' . $item->getUid(), 'RecordName_pid_' . $item->getPid()]);
```

[1] https://git.typo3.org/Packages/TYPO3.CMS.git/commitdiff/b8621ebfe2b65826d25e80519209e5420df436a8?hp=e664996d6eb096555496774658093bf220566933

Answer (score 0):

I would create the tag by using a ViewHelper which is then called in the List view

Comment: Hmm, I don't get your point - and how you then delete caches for all views where this item is displayed (single, list and others) while it is possible to add only one tag for view?